# Countable Zariski closed set is finite

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $X\subsetneq \mathbb A^n$ be Zariski closed and countable. Is $X$ then finite?

If $n=1$, then its clear, because the Zariski closed sets in $\mathbb A^1$ are just the zero set of some polynomial, so every Zariski closed set is finite.

But what about higher dimensions?

**Definition of $\mathbb A^n$:**
We define affine $n$-space over $k$, 
denoted $\mathbb A^n$, to be the set of all $n$-tuples of elements of $k$.

**Edit**: Parthiv Basu already gave a valid answer to this question.
However, I forgot to mentaion that I want to work over an **algebraically closed field $k$**.  Actually, I had $k = \mathbb C$ in mind. I posted this as a new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292896/algebraic-subset-of-mathbb-cn-is-finite-if-it-is-countable)

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I added the definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are considering the affine $n$-space over some field $\mathbb{k}$ then it is certainly true that the closed subsets in $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{k})$ are just $\emptyset$, finite subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{k})$ and $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{k})$ itself. But for $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Q})$, the unit circle $V(x^2 + y^2-1)$ is a closed countable set but not finite.

Comment: I see,.. I had an algebraically closed field in mind. But thank you

Comment: An algebraically closed field can be countable.

Comment: @EricWofsey: I don't understand your comment. Considering the upvotes, it seems helpful, but I don't see how.

Comment: @tralala The algebraic closure of a finite field is countable. And any non-constant polynomial over any algebraically closed field has infinitely many roots. So my answer works for that case too.

Comment: @tralala But for $k = \mathbb{C}$ your claim is correct. If the dimension of the Zariski closed subset is greater than $0$ than it has to be an uncountable set by Noether Normalization. But in the zero dimensional case, the Zariski closed subset can only have finitely many points.

Comment: @ParthivBasu "any non-constant polynomial over any algebraically closed field has infinitely many roots" is not true, take $k= \mathbb C$.

Comment: @tralala Right. I meant a polynomial with more than  $1$ variable.