# Algebraic subset of $\mathbb C^n$ is finite if it is countable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Let $X\subset \mathbb C^n$ be Zariski closed and countable. Why is $X$
>   finite?

So far I noticed that it is true for $n=1$, because if $X$ is algebraic, then it is the zero set of a polynomial and thus finite.
Also, the claim is not true for the euclidean topology, because lattices are closed.

Maybe a compactness argument works?

---

This is a follow up to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292106/countable-zariski-closed-set-is-finite/3292138?noredirect=1#comment6772009_3292138), where I asked about a more general setting, but actually had this in mind.
There, it was pointed out, that the assertion is true and a strategy was proposed in the comments. However, I do not understand it.
I think its best to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Very related question, it answers yours quite directly; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938690/why-is-a-zariski-closed-set-compact-under-the-zariski-topology

Comment: @Servaes I don't see how compactness answers this question "directly". It is certainly possible for a compact subset of an uncountable topological space to be countably infinite. Perhaps you could explain more?

Comment: @Servaes: How does it answer my question directly? Compactness of $X$ does in general not imply finiteness, as the counter example in my previous question shows.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You are right, there is still some work to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand on my comments. Let $ V=V(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ be your Zariski closed subset, where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Suppose V has dimension $m > 0$. By a geometric version of Noether's Normalization lemma (you'll find it in [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319167206)) there exists a surjective map $\pi: V \to \mathbb{C}^m$. So a positive dimensional $V$ cannot be countable. Now if $V$ is zero dimensional, this means the dimension of the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_n)$ is finite. So any $1,x_i, x_i^2,\dots $ must have linear relationship between them, so $(f_1, \dots, f_n) \cap \mathbb{C}[x_i] \neq {0}$ for all $i$. This implies $V$ must be finite.

Comment: I need a little bit more help with the last part. $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_n)$ is of dimension $0$, so every ideal is prime and thus it is a field. How do you proceed then?

Comment: The Krull dimension is indeed $0$ but this just means that every prime ideal in it is maximal and not that it is a field. If it were a field, it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and thus a zero dimensional vector space. Now $1, x_i, x_i^2, \dots$ considered as elements of this finite dimensional vector space must have a linear relationship between them, otherwise it would mean the vector space is infinite dimensional. This implies there is a polynomial, say $g$, in $\mathbb{C}[x_i]$ which is equal to $0$ mod $(f_1,\dots, f_n)$, that is, $g \in (f_1,\dots, f_n)$.

Comment: Now the set of solutions of $V$ is bounded by the product of the set of (finite) solutions of each such $g$ in $\mathbb{C}[x_i]$ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: I think I got it. Please tell me if I am right. For each, $i=1,\dots,n$ we choose such $g_i$. Then $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\in V$ implies $g_i(x_i)=0$ for each $i$. So if $V_i:=V(g_i)$, then $V\subset V_i \times \dots \times V_n$. As each $V_i$ is finite, so is their product and thus $V$.

Comment: @tralala Correct. :-)

Comment: Correction: My first comment said it would be a zero dimensional vector space. I meant one dimensional. Not that it matters to our problem.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from [Noether normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma), which says (among other things) that if $V$ is an irreducible affine variety of dimension $d$, then there is a surjective morphism $V\to\mathbb{A}^d$.  So if $X$ is a variety of positive dimension over $\mathbb{C}$, this immediately implies it is uncountable.  If $X$ has dimension $0$, then each irreducible component of $X$ is just a point and so $X$ must be finite.

Comment: I follow you up to the last sentence. What is the problem with having infinite irreducible components?

Comment: Any Noetherian space has only finitely may irreducible components, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0052.